# Electron version 2.0.12 giving error after installing

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I installed electron in ubuntu 20.04

`npm i -g electron@2.0.12`

but after installing when I do electron -v

it gives me this error

`(electron:11714): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:05:04.660: cannot open display: :0.0`
I tried a lot of things found on internet but nothing worked

Comment: Electron v2.0.12 is an extremely old version, the newest version is 12.0.5 and I'd recommend
 upgrading.

Comment: I have updated it but the project which I am cloning it is using this version and it is showing this problem

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/use-nightmarejs-to-automate-headless-browsing/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Node.js v10.7.0.

It's the version of Node.js version that was around when Electron v2.0.12 was released.